# weird AXIOS post request headers setting in react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios, authorization

I have this react button function in my script

I have googled it

people said you gotta put the double quote like below

```
"Authorization": `Bearer ${cookies.Token}`
```

I have tried on the content-type and it works

I can post stuff

however, when I do the same thing with Authorization and run the program again

VS code erased my double code and becomes

```
Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.Token}`
```

and then I console.log the token on the other side

it becomes undefined

[image]

please help me out here

what is eventually the correct way to set headers

```
 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const finalRecipe = { ...recipe };
      if (!finalRecipe.imageUrl) {
        finalRecipe.imageUrl = defaultImageUrl;
      }
      const result = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/recipe/create",
        data: finalRecipe,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies.Token}`,
        },
      });

      alert("recipe created");
      navigate("/");
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) alert(JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
    }
  };
```

I can also view the token value from the browser

[image]

added the entire cookie property here

[image]

below is the value of the cookie.Token I got from console.log in frontend
[image]

I have added{ useCookies } in my script

```
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const CreateRecipe = () => {
  const userId = useGetUserID(); // for below userOwner

  const [cookies, _] = useCookies("token");
```

Comment: If the result if `"Bearer undefined"` then that *pretty strongly implies* that `cookies.Token` has a value of `undefined`.  In your browser's debugging tools, is that the value being sent to the server in the request?  When you debug your client-side code, what is the observed runtime value of `cookies.Token`?  Or of `cookies`?  What do you expect it to be and why?

Comment: yes, I can see it from the token in cookies on my browser @David

Comment: The picture you've added just now *very clearly shows* that the value of `undefined` is being sent to the server.  So "VS Code" isn't doing anything to this value.  That's the value your client-side code is providing to the server, so that's the value the server has.  You're focusing your debugging efforts in the wrong place.  It's time for you to start debugging the *client-side* code to find where you're populating that `cookies` variable and what value(s) you're providing it.

Comment: but I can get the value of my token in my client side
please check another update pic above @David

Comment: so I am guessing  the format I have set is wrong,
 since I can console.log the value of it in frontend
and I can view the value on cookies in my browser @David

Comment: And where *specifically* are you outputting that value?  Currently you're just insisting that you *must* be correct and the JavaScript engine *must* be wrong, which is highly unlikely.  If the value is `undefined` then the value is `undefined`.  It might be defined in another context or at a later time.  We can't know.  Please take some time to provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @David sorry, I didn't mean it, my guess to this issue is 
I am not using the correct way to set the header in post request

Comment: And your guess is wrong.  Your own debugging observations presented in the question above ***very clearly shows*** that you are sending the header in the request.  The problem is that the header doesn't have the *value* you want it to have.  So you'll need to stop assuming and start debugging where specifically that value comes from.

Comment: @David oh you are right since I just found out that I have the" bearer "in it but I dun have the value of the token

Answer (score 0):

There's no such object `cookie` but there is another document property `cookies` which you probably need. Also it is usually stored as a semicolon separated string, so you need something like that as I understand:

```
const cookieValue = document.cookie
      .split("; ")
      .find((row) => row.startsWith("Token="))
      ?.split("=")[1];
```

Here is more examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: oh, sorry, forgive me, I didn't mention that I have added {useCookie} in above script